# Prove $\sin(1/x)$ is discontinuous at 0 using epsilon delta definition of continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if $x=0$,}\\
\sin(1/x) &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$ Prove that $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ using the $\epsilon \delta$ definition of continuity.

I know that the $\epsilon, \delta$ criterion is as follows: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x\in A$, if $|x-x_0|\lt \delta$ implies that  $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\lt \epsilon$.

I am unsure how to go about writing the proof and any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you see intuitively why the function is not continuous (and your question is just with expressing that intuition as a proof), or do you need help understanding why it is discontinuous at all?

Comment: Both would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried sketching a graph of the function?

Comment: Ok, yeah, I can see why it's discontinuous, thanks.

Comment: Does it make sense to show that lim sin as x goes to infinity is not well defined and thus lim sin (1/x) as x goes to 0 is not well defined?

Answer (score 6):

Take the sequence $x_n = \frac{2}{(4n+1) \pi}$. Then $x_n \to 0$ so if $f$ was continuous, we would have $f(x_n) \to f(0) = 0$. However, $f(x_n) = 1$ for all $n$, so clearly we can't have $f(x_n) \to 0$ and thus $f$ isn't continuous.

Using $\epsilon, \delta$: set $\epsilon = 1/2$. Then for any $\delta >0$, we can find $n$ so that $x_n = \frac{2}{(4n+1) \pi} < \delta$. Then $\lvert f(x_n) - f(0) \rvert = \lvert f(x_n) \rvert = 1 \ge \epsilon.$ That is, for this specific $\epsilon$, there is no $\delta > 0$ which guarantees $\lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert < \epsilon$ for all $\lvert x - 0 \rvert < \delta$. Hence $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let y=1/x . The limit as y goes to infinity of sin(y) is undefined because sin is periodic. But this is the limit from the right of sin(1/x) as x goes to 0 (and is still undefined). In particular the right-hand limit is not 0 and thus the general limit is not 0. It follows that the function is discontinuous at 0.

Answer (score 0):

The key idea of the $\epsilon-\delta$ or the formal continuity definition is that **if** for an **arbitrarily** small $\epsilon$ neighbourhood "of" $f$ around $f_0$ there exists at least some $\delta$ neighbourhood "in" $x$ around $x_0$ that always maps to within that $f$ space neighbourhood, $f$ is continuous.

So to show a function is discontinuous, *one* approach is to show that no matter the $\delta$ disk one tries to choose, the image of that disk always has a minimum size. As a result, $\epsilon$ neighbourhoods "of" $f$ that are smaller, are ruled out, breaking continuity.

We have been asked about continuity around $0$ so let's look at a $\delta$ neighbourhood of $0$ and try to estimate the size of its image. One point that this neighbourhood certainly contains is its center, $0$, so the image of this neighbourhood certainly contains $f(0)$ ($=0$ here but I leave it symbolic for arbitrary choices). Now are there any other "easy" points we know the value of $\sin$ at? Of course - integer multiples of $\pi/2$. So, whenever $1/x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi/2$, $\sin(1/x)$ will take on values $0$ or $1$ (or $-1$ but I am ignoring negative values to keep everything simpler. Also, if you do not like these 'integer multiples of $\pi/2$,  you can choose any other value of $x$ that you have memorized $\sin$ by heart at, provided $\sin(1/ x)$ isn't $f(0)$ at all of them)

How does this solve the question? **If every**  $\delta$-neighbourhood contains any of those 'easy' points, then the image set of that disk will necessarily contain $\{0,1,f(0)\}$. Since the size of such a disk is at least one as $|1-0|=1$ regardless of $f(0)$, this dooms $f$ to discontinuity.  The epsilons who are  less than $1$ will never find an appropriate $\delta$ (and forever roam in loneliness)

So, does our neighbourhood contain such points? Yes, since you can always find an $x$ in **any** $\delta$- neighbourhood around $0$ such that $\sin(1/x)=0 ~ \text{or} ~ 1$. These are precisely the $x<\delta$ that also satisfy $\frac{1}{x}=n \pi/2$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

---

PS: I wrote this verbose, relaxed explanation just to convince myself of and possibly help future beginners about what was going on. In essence, it says nothing more and certainly less, than [User8128's terse answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1973485/614342).